# Is that possible to get comments with macro?

Tags: macros, elixir

I was trying to parse some code and reformat them, but it seems that quote will just ignore the comments.

Is there any way to achieve this? I guess I have to dive into the erlang side?

Comment: If you can't get the comments inside Elixir macros, you might just want to process the raw source directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot get code comments inside macros. They never become part of the AST and are discarded still in Elixir's tokenizer.

Comment: So, I guess it not possible to override any functions in `:elixir` module?  If so, would you consider optionally preserve comments in tokenizer?

Comment: I am ok with a patch that preserves comments in the tokenizer as long as it is not the default behaviour as it would severely complicate the parser. That said, I don't think patching only the tokenizer would help you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that comments are handled at the tokenizer level, so the parser will not even see them. The [relevant](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/e49a806e8abe43c62c9c1b21ea7eb2217bef1966/lib/elixir/src/elixir_tokenizer.erl#L144-L146) [parts](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/e49a806e8abe43c62c9c1b21ea7eb2217bef1966/lib/elixir/src/elixir_tokenizer.erl#L788-L791) from the elixir tokenizer indicate that comments are discarded pretty early in the pipeline. [This test case](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/e49a806e8abe43c62c9c1b21ea7eb2217bef1966/lib/elixir/test/erlang/tokenizer_test.erl#L74-L75) from elixir core tells us the same thing:

```
comments_test() ->
  [{number, {1,1,2}, 1},{eol, {1,3,4}},{number,{2,1,2},2}] = tokenize("1 # Comment\n2").
```