# Multiline comment in Elixir

Tags: comments, multiline, elixir

Most languages allow block comments, and multiline commands.

For example, a multiline comment in HTML looks like the following:

```
<!-- 
Warning, brave programmer:
Here be dragons.
-->
```

In Elixir, the closest thing I have found comes from EEx ([docs](https://hexdocs.pm/eex/EEx.html)).

EEx smartengine `<% #comments %>` seem to be discarded from source, even if they are multiline. However, this is just a workaround.

Does Elixir have a multiline comment feature, or a way to instruct the compiler to discard text from the compiled .beam file?

Comment: Is there some issue with using the # on multiple lines?  Lots of editors have support for automatic insertion of comment characters at the beginning of a set of marked lines.

Comment: Sometimes when you commit code, you might not want to change the commit history of specific lines, at least for my use case.

Comment: // , No issue, it's just a question

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Elixir does not have multiline comments.**

However, one very common use case for multiline comments is documenting modules and functions, for which you can use the [module attributes `@doc` and `@moduledoc`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html) together with [heredocs](http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#lists-and-binaries).

```
defmodule MyModule do
  @moduledoc """
  This module is great at X
  """

  @doc """
  Frobnicates the given string.
  """
  def frobnicate(s) do
  end
end
```

Comment: // , Actually, I didn't want to put this in the question since I get accused of being long winded a lot, but I'm trying to convert my projects over to the Literate Programming technique. I'm told I have a rather odd way of going about things, and I will not be the one maintaining my project. A sort of intermediate step in this conversion will, I suspect, involve massive strings that I would rather not have end up in my `.beam`s. Do the `@moduledoc` and `@doc` end up in compiled code? Do Literate Programming tools exist that use Elixir-lang?

Comment: // , Maybe I should ask these as separate stackoverflow.com questions.

Comment: Yes, the module attributes end up in the beam file, so we can look up documentation for a module in iex, for example. I am not aware of literate programming tools for elixir, but that obiously doesn't mean they don't exist. Are you sure the comments end up in the BEAM file? I think they should be discarded.

Comment: I need to clarify the thing with module attributes: "normal" module attributes do _not_ end up in the BEAM file. The special ones listed in the documentation also are discarded, but they are used to generate documentation, which in turn ends up in the BEAM file.

Comment: // , As to "Are you sure the comments end up in the BEAM file?", did I imply that I thought that comments were ending up in the BEAM file? 
Also, I think I like the sound of that "'normal' module attributes do not end up in the BEAM file." bit. Could that be a way to make multi-liners that the compiler discards? Am I edging into bad programming practices, here? I don't want to teach the little chickadees bad habits.

Comment: I think using module attributes to do literate programming feels wrong. I am quite sure that comments do not end up in the BEAM file, they are discarded by the tokenizer. See this recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543321/is-that-possible-to-get-comments-with-macro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80142/discussion-between-37coins-and-patrick-oscity).

Comment: There is some confusion here. The documentation is stored in the BEAM file but it is not loaded when the module code is loaded. It is stored in a special chunk, which is loaded only when needed, similar to how the abstract code is stored. Other than that, attributes aren't stored in the BEAM file too, unless explicitly configured.

Comment: You'll probably want to use `@moduledoc ~S"""` and `@doc ~S"""` to avoid interpolation.

Comment: // , Accepted for clear and direct **Elixir does not have multiline comments.** at the top, and for the exemplary levels of scrubious frobnication.

Answer (score 17):

I try to just use """ to quickly comment code a la Python, without turning it into a documentation

```
"""
def some_function() do
  some_code    
end
"""
```

Comment: // , Ah, but does it end up in the `.beam` file?

Comment: I'm gonna go on a BEAM rabbit hole now, will report back.

Comment: This gives a warning `warning: code block contains unused literal "THESE ARE COMMENTS\n" (remove the literal or assign it to _ to avoid warnings)`

Comment: @mraaroncruz would assigning `_ = """` work to not show those warnings?

Comment: @owyongsk yep that works for me. It's hacky, but seems to satisfy credo

Comment: I've been using `_comment = """` to make it a bit clearer instead of plain `"_ = """`

Answer (score 13):

Macros could help here to some degree:

```ruby
defmodule Comment do
  defmacro comment(_text) do
  end
end

defmodule TestComment do
  import Comment

  comment """
  Module
  Comment
  """

  def func do
    comment """
    Function
    Comment
    """
  end
end
```

Comment: // , This does not seem as 'proper' an answer as using the `@moduledoc` and `@doc`, but it answers the specific question more directly.

Comment: // , Would this text be present in the BEAM file?

Comment: @NathanBasanese: the text is discarded by the macro, so it won't even be in the AST after macro processing. So no, it will not make it into the BEAM file.

Comment: // , Given that this will not end up in the `.beam` file, I'm liking this answer a bit more. For the curious, "AST" in the above comment refers to an "Abstract Syntax Tree". You can search in the page at the following link for Abstract Syntax Tree for a good bit of context beyond the generic WikiPedia article. #nocsdegree

Comment: `docp` and `doc` generate warnings by the compiler. I think this is by far the best solution. It's just not standard practice.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use module attributes for multiline comments, no macro required.  I typically use the following for documenting/commenting private functions:

```
@docp """
This is my
multi line
comment
"""
```

Comment: This has to be the absolutely simplest and cleanest way of doing multiline comments!

Comment: `warning: module attribute @docp was set but never used`

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I think that started in Elixir 1.4.x so I no longer use that strategy for the same reason.  I'm back to mostly using comments.  Although in a few cases I have actually created a macro called `docp` that compiles to nothing.

Comment: How about just """ without the @docp?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late and that this question has already been answered, but I found a way that works, using a sigil that prevents string interpolation. I figured I could share it for others who stumble upon this post.

```
~S"""
Hi! 
I'm a
multiline comment!
"""
```

This works in modules and functions too, including if it is the last thing in the block. Unlike regular string literals (i.e. without the `~s` sigil prepended to it), this does not throw an error or warning.

**Keep in mind that this is not an official language feature.** Out of the box, Elixir only supports single-line comments (`# Comment`) and the module documentation syntax (`@moduledoc` / `@doc`).