# Is there any way to comment out line(s) of code in function in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Is there any ways to comment out a line or lines of code in a function?

something like the following

```
defmodule MyModule
  def foo do
    //a = "old code"
    a = "new code"
  end
end
```

or

```
defmodule MyModule
  def foo do
    /*a = "old code"
    b = 1234 */
    a = "new code"
  end
end
```

Comment: Downvote.  Literally the first result on google for "elixir comment syntax" discusses exactly this question. Really appears to have put forth zero research effort.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I mostly search on elixir-lang.org which I couldn't find the answer at. I think 'comment' is very vague for google to find and for elixir it kept returning the doc comment stuff.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Comments in Elixir, as is common in languages that can function as scripting languages, use the pound sign.

```
defmodule MyModule
  def foo do
    # a = "old code"
    a = "new code"
  end
end
```

Formally, there's no way to have a multiline comment, but a multiline string will end up being a noop.

```
defmodule MyModule
  def foo do
    """
    a = "old code"
    a = "more old code"
    """
    a = "new code"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm far from an expert, but I don't think this answer works in all cases. If the multi-line string is at the end of a function it will be returned as the function's result. So I think the following reordering of the answer's code fails (or at least doesn't operate as expected). It returns `"a = \"old code\"\na = \"more old code\"\n"`. Also note that there is a missing `do` in the answer on the `defmodule` line. Finally, code using `"""` for multiple comments will generate an `unused literal` error (whereas `'''` will not).

```
defmodule MyModule do
  def foo do
    a = "new code"
    """
    a = "old code"
    a = "more old code"
    """
  end
end
```

So, if the multi-line comment technique doesn't work (in all cases), how should we block out a section of code?

You can't set an attribute (e.g. `@comment """...` inside a function) so that won't work.

You could use macros as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749094/multiline-comment-in-elixir) but that "pollutes" the code a bit.

I've Googled around a bit and can not find a suitable answer (maybe I'm missing something obvious) so I'll just hack up some `elisp` code to block out a section in Emacs by prepending each line with `#` (if it's not already in the Elixir mode package).

Comment: @AI: Commenting out a section of code in emacs is already standard feature for (practically) any language supported. Mark the area (CTRL-SPACE at the beginning, go to the end of the region); then do `M-x comment-region` <ENTER>).